# Developing add-ons/extensions for MS Project

Tags: add-in, ms-project

I would like to write a quick UI addon for MS Project, but I don't know how to proceed. Ideally it should be fully integrated into Project. Just need to know how to get started. Thanks!

Comment: what language are you going to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if using Visual Studio:
Check out Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905533.aspx